# Ping test a large number of devices - reset their LAN Switch port if they fail the test

Tags: shell, testing, networking, interface, reset

I've an environment with over 3000 CCTV cameras all powered by PoE via the connected LAN Switch port. What I want to do is either find a working solution or write a script to test ping response from the cameras and if any fail the test reset the Switch interface the camera is connected to. We have a Solarwinds (NPM, UDT & NCM) monitoring solution in place which could be used to do this else we can consider other tools (Open Source or otherwise). I've asked the Forum for Solarwinds about this already.

Has anyone done something similar in their own environment? Is there an obvious tool that can do this or some similar script I could use (as a 'wannabe' coder) to get me started. I've Netmiko collecting data from many of the Switches involved already for example.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same, but I did a demo on port security once, which also requires resetting ports (https://ljm.home.xs4all.nl/portsecurity/index.html if you're interested).

A failing ping with the default value would take around 10 seconds; you may want to shorten that period.

There is also the question on how you would reset the port. That depends a lot on the switch hardware that is used, the security requirement on your network etc. Ideally, you would use ssh to access your switch, but you may even be stuck with telnet.

You should probably want to keep the camera/switch/port config in a separate file.

So a first order approach would be:

```
while read ip switch port ; do
    if ping -c1 -W1 $ip ; then
        echo "$ip is alive"
    else
        ssh $switch shut $port
        sleep 1
        ssh $switch enable $port
    fi
done < file_with_configdata
```

There is a lot wrong with this code, no quoting, I don't know how to access your switch, you may want to read up a bit on `read`, tune the ping time-out etcetera. See this as a bit of pseudo-code.

If you get even more cameras, you may want to do a number of pings parallel.